# how to list new add file after update in SVN?

Tags: svn

svn diff -r version_1:version_2
in SVN, we can diff log, like above,but it show a lot of change,too detail for me .
what I need just to diff the version_1 and version_2, who's the new add file. is someone know?

Answer (score 1):

```
svn diff -r version1:version2 --summarize
```

That will give you a list of changed files, similar to `svn status`. Just take the ones with `A`.

Answer (score 0):

`svn diff -rversion_1:version_2 --summarize`